# SAS: PROC SQL: How to convert a character format column to time format

Tags: sql, sas

I have a column which is character format and has entries as `hh:mm:ss`. How can I convert character format to time format using `proc sql` in sas?

Comment: Please show what you've tried in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the input function with a format (time8.) to convert the value. The original column will not change its type from char, so you can create another column to hold the numeric value.

If you need something else then please edit your question with an expanded explanation and an example.

```
/* set up data */
data have;
   input char_time : $8.;
   datalines;
00:00:00
01:02:03
23:59:59
;

/* create a column in time8. format */
proc sql noprint;
   create table
      want as
   select
       char_time
      ,input(char_time,time8.) as num_time format = time8.
   from
      have
   ;
quit;
```